# How to display zone configuration with dnscmd?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dnscmd

I am trying to display/export the current zone configuration using the `dnscmd` (Windows) but so far it seems that the `/zoneprint` does output only the records from the DNS zone but I am interested about all the other parameters that can be modified using the `/config`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
C:\>dnscmd /ZoneInfo

Usage: DnsCmd <Server> /ZoneInfo <ZoneName> [<Property>]
  <Property> -- zone property to view
  Examples:
    AllowUpdate
    DsIntegrated
    Aging
    RefreshInterval
    NoRefreshInterval
    IsSigned
    Keymaster
    IsKeymaster
    SignWithNSEC3
    NSEC3HashAlgorithm
    NSEC3Iterations
    NSEC3RandomSaltLength
    NSEC3UserSalt
    NSEC3CurrentSalt
    NSEC3OptOut
    MaintainTrustAnchor
    SignatureInceptionOffset
    DNSKEYRecordSetTTL
    DSRecordSetTTL
    SecureDelegationPollingPeriod
    DsRecordAlgorithms
    RFC5011KeyRollovers
    SigningKeyDescriptors
    PropagationTime
    ParentHasSecureDelegation

In future versions of Windows, Microsoft might remove dnscmd.exe.

If you currently use dnscmd.exe to configure and manage the DNS server,
Microsoft recommends that you transition to Windows PowerShell.
```

With no specific properties specified:

```
C:\>dnscmd . /ZoneInfo lab.contoso.com

Zone query result:

Zone info:
        ptr                   = 0000009D181ECBF0
        zone name             = lab.contoso.com
        zone type             = 1
        shutdown              = 0
        paused                = 0
        update                = 2
        DS integrated         = 1
        read only zone        = 0
        in DS loading queue   = 0
        currently DS loading  = 0
        data file             = (null)
        using WINS            = 0
        using Nbstat          = 0
        aging                 = 0
          refresh interval    = 168
          no refresh          = 168
          scavenge available  = 0
        Zone Masters    NULL IP Array.
        Zone Secondaries        NULL IP Array.
        secure secs           = 3
        directory partition   = AD-Domain     flags 00000015
        zone DN               = DC=lab.contoso.com,cn=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=lab,DC=contoso,DC=com
Command completed successfully.
```

Specifying a specific parameter:

```
C:\>dnscmd . /ZoneInfo lab.contoso.com AllowUpdate

Zone query result:
Dword:  2 (00000002)

Command completed successfully.
```

Might also want to check the `/ExportSettings` parameter. It spits out a pretty exhaustive text file.